# Stanford CoreNLP OpenIE annotator

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I have a question regarding Stanford CoreNLP OpenIE annotator.

I am using Stanford CoreNLP version **stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09** in order to extract relations using OpenIE. I don't know much Java that's why I am using the `pycorenlp` wrapper for Python 3.4.

I want to extract relation between all words of a sentence, below is the code I used. I am also interested in showing the confidence of each triplet:

```
import nltk
from pycorenlp import *
import collections
nlp=StanfordCoreNLP("http://localhost:9000/")
s="Twenty percent electric motors are pulled from an assembly line"
output = nlp.annotate(s, properties={"annotators":"tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse,natlog,openie",
                                 "outputFormat": "json","triple.strict":"true"})
result = [output["sentences"][0]["openie"] for item in output]
print(result)
for i in result:
for rel in i:
    relationSent=rel['relation'],rel['subject'],rel['object']
    print(relationSent)
```

This is the result i got:

```
[[{'relationSpan': [4, 6], 'subject': 'Twenty percent electric motors', 'objectSpan': [8, 10], 'relation': 'are pulled from', 'object': 'assembly line', 'subjectSpan': [0, 4]}, {'relationSpan': [4, 6], 'subject': 'percent electric motors', 'objectSpan': [8, 10], 'relation': 'are pulled from', 'object': 'assembly line', 'subjectSpan': [1, 4]}, {'relationSpan': [4, 5], 'subject': 'Twenty percent electric motors', 'objectSpan': [5, 6], 'relation': 'are', 'object': 'pulled', 'subjectSpan': [0, 4]}, {'relationSpan': [4, 5], 'subject': 'percent electric motors', 'objectSpan': [5, 6], 'relation': 'are', 'object': 'pulled', 'subjectSpan': [1, 4]}]]
```

And the triplets are:

```
('are pulled from', 'Twenty percent electric motors', 'assembly line')
('are pulled from', 'percent electric motors', 'assembly line')
('are', 'Twenty percent electric motors', 'pulled')
('are', 'percent electric motors', 'pulled')
```

First problem is that the confidence is not showing in the result. Second problem is that I only want to retrieve the triplet that that includes all words of the sentence i.e this triplet:

```
('are pulled from', 'Twenty percent electric motors', 'assembly line')
```

What I’m getting is more than one combination of triplets. I tried to use the option `"triple.strict":"true"` because it extracts "triples only if they consume the entire fragment" but it is NOT working.

Can anyone advise me on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try this setting:

```
"openie.triple.strict":"true"
```

Looking through the code it appears at this time the confidence is not stored with the returned json, so you cannot get that from the CoreNLP server.

Since you bring this up I will push a change that will add those to the output json and let you know when that is live on the GitHub.

Comment: `openie.triple.strict = true` makes sure that the segmenter understands all of the components of the fragment its segmenting. I suspect you'll have more luck setting `max_entailments_per_clause = 1` and `splitter.disable = true`.

Comment: StanfordNLPHelp Can you please tell if returning of confidence from server in the json is fixed? Thanks

Comment: I'm trying this in 2019 with coreNLP 3.9.2 and i'm not seeing confidence scores. @StanfordNLPHelp did this ever get implemented?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot, it is working now i added both: "openie.triple.strict":"true" and "openie.max_entailments_per_clause":"1" the code now is:

```
output = nlp.annotate(chunkz, properties={"annotators":"tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse,natlog,openie",
                                "outputFormat": "json",
                                 "openie.triple.strict":"true",
                                 "openie.max_entailments_per_clause":"1"})
```

Comment: Hey, I think you should have added `splitter.disable = true` as Gabor Angeli suggested. Also, how do you manage to get confidence scores now?